# Mounting Exfat Xubuntu 16.04, exfat-utils/-fuse doesn't work

Tags: mount, xubuntu, hard-drive, exfat

Error:

> Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/smalltooth/Minibrick: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/smalltooth/Minibrick"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
>
> stdout:
>
> 'FUSE exfat 1.2.3'
>
> stderr:
>
> `WARN: volume was not unmounted cleanly.
> ERROR: fsync failed: Remote I/O error.'.

Comment: You need to use the native Widows error correction tool. Yu cannot repair exfat in Linux.

Comment: I am not sure if it is correct, but I made a new post. I attempted to run the drive through Windows error correction. It reports no issues. I also safely removed the drive. I am getting the same error. Is there anything else it may mean?